# Django AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two apps `peaceout` and `food`.
`peaceout` has a model `User` and I have imported `User` in `food` model. 
and I am getting the following error when I am running `python manage.py syncdb`

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/madhu/Documents/django/my_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/madhu/Documents/django/my_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/madhu/Documents/django/my_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/madhu/Documents/django/my_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/madhu/Documents/django/my_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/madhu/Documents/django/my_project/pps/food/models.py", line 37, in <module>
    class Order(models.Model):
  File "/Users/madhu/Documents/django/my_project/pps/food/models.py", line 39, in Order
    user = models.Model(User)
  File "/Users/madhu/Documents/django/my_project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 399, in __init__
    if args_len > len(self._meta.concrete_fields):
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

My model class where I am using `User` model is

```
class Order(models.Model):
    itemDict = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    user = models.Model(User)
    cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slot = models.Model(OrderSlot)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

Here is my [Food Models.py](http://pastebin.com/N6vQDxaH) 
and here is my [Peaceout Models.py](http://pastebin.com/DDT5ASbL)

Comment: You link modes with `models.ForeignKey`, not `models.Model`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you define the relation to the `User` model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    itemDict = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    user = models.Model(User)  # <- HERE
```

If you want `Order` to have a link to a user who placed it, use [`ForeignKey` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

<sup>Check the "slot" model also. Same problem.</sup>